# How to store value of checked item in arrayList using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before I had used the `class` for getting the value of `checked` checkbox storing in array.

```
<div class="form-check">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label> <input id="check_id" type="checkbox"
         value=1 class="chk" /> <span>Invoice</span>
      </label>
      <label> <input id="check_id" type="checkbox"
         value=2 class="chk" /> <span>Packing List</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

And it was successfully stored in array as  :

```
$(".chk").click(function() {
         getValueUsingClass();
    });

    function getValueUsingClass(){
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
            chkArray[i] = $(this).val();
        });
    }
```

It was working fine until i changed the class name from `.chk1` and `.chk2`. So I needed to change the **class to chk1 and chk2**

```
<div class="form-check">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label> <input id="check_id" type="checkbox"
         value=1 class="chk1" /> <span>Invoice</span>
      </label>
      <label> <input id="check_id" type="checkbox"
         value=2 class="chk2" /> <span>Packing List</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

There may be more than these 2 checkboxes(I have only shown 2 as it is dynamic)  there may be checkbox from **.chk1 to .chk15** .How can i store checked checkbox in array when their class name is different?

Comment: you can try using the class starts with. `$(input[class^='chk'])`

Comment: my suggestion will be to have a common class name for js/jquery selection and rest for css. for example: `class="chk chk1"` and `class="chk chk2"` and rest all to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Starts with from [jQuery Starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

You can use this as `$(input[class^='chk'])`

```js
$('input[class^="chk"]').click(function() {
  var arr = getValueUsingClass();
  console.log(arr);
});

function getValueUsingClass() {
  var chkArray = [];
  $('input[class^="chk"]:checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
    chkArray[i] = $(this).val();
  });
  return chkArray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label> <input  type="checkbox"
         value=1 class="chk1" /> <span>Invoice</span>
      </label>
    <label> <input  type="checkbox"
         value=2 class="chk2" /> <span>Packing List</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```js
$("input[class^=chk]").click(function() {
   
   $('#result').html(getValueUsingClass().join(" | "));
});

function getValueUsingClass(){

  
  var arr = [];
           $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
              arr.push($(this).val());
           });
           return arr; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label> <input id="check_id1" type="checkbox"
         value=1 class="chk1" /> <span>Invoice</span>
      </label>
      <label> <input id="check_id2" type="checkbox"
         value=2 class="chk2" /> <span>Packing List</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div><div id="result"></div>
```

Please let me know your views over it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) that selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

**Please Note:** The attribute [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) must be unique in a document.

```js
$("input[class^=chk]").click(function() {
   getValueUsingClass();
});

function getValueUsingClass(){
  var chkArray = [];
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      chkArray.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(chkArray);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label> <input id="check_id1" type="checkbox"
         value=1 class="chk1" /> <span>Invoice</span>
      </label>
      <label> <input id="check_id2" type="checkbox"
         value=2 class="chk2" /> <span>Packing List</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does id affects in the code? i have the same id  for both of them and i am geting [1,1,2] in array in console

Comment: @ashwinkarki, id must be unique in a document....there is no relation with that, I simply changed that as this not valid.....

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this without any class name:

```
function getValueUsingClass(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i){
        chkArray[i] = $(this).val();
    });
}
```